# How to stop Visual Studio adding using statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When creating a new class, Visual Studio automatically adds using statements. How do I control what it puts there or stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this article on customizing your Visual Studio template files: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/11/05/2556.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the other options below are nice, but this was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Do `Add/New Item/Code/CodeFile` instead.  An empty class file will be created.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be exactly what you want, but it will work if you want to cleanup any unused usings:

```
Edit->IntelliSense->Organize Usings->Remove Unused Usings
```

Comment: This is also a useful item to create a keyboard shortcut for.